# if statement returns false when values are outputting the same

Tags: php

I am trying to compare a row returned by mysql and whats extracted in my code however it keeps returning false when strlen returns the same and they output the exact same.

```
if(trim($checkComplete['WorkOrder']) == trim($wo)) {
    //Do nothing
} else {
    //WorkOrder does not match
    echo "WorkOrder does not match!<br>".$wo." | ". $checkCompleteAssoc['WorkOrder']."<br>";
    echo strlen($wo)."<br>";
    echo strlen($checkCompleteAssoc['WorkOrder'])."<br>";
```

Output:

```
WorkOrder does not match!
39809337 | 39809337
8
8
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($wo)` and `var_dump($checkCompleteAssoc['WorkOrder'])` show?

Comment: in if use `$checkCompleteAssoc` instead of `$checkComplete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you using wrong variable `$checkComplete`

```
if(trim($checkCompleteAssoc['WorkOrder']) == trim($wo)) {
    //Do nothing
} else {
    //WorkOrder does not match
    echo "WorkOrder does not match!<br>".$wo." | ". $checkCompleteAssoc['WorkOrder']."<br>";
    echo strlen($wo)."<br>";
    echo strlen($checkCompleteAssoc['WorkOrder'])."<br>";
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: its an answer, to just checking he did by mistake ?

Comment: If you aren't sure if that variable is correct or not, how can you be sure this answer is correct? And if you have to end your answer with a question mark it might not be a good answer.

Comment: @JohnConde - You're Right, I'll improve it, Thanks :)

Comment: @Ahmed Ginani it should be a comment not an answer

Comment: @BunkerBoy - Should I delete this ?

Comment: No. Since it turned out to be the right answer you should remove your question mark and make your answer a *statement*.

Comment: @ Ahmed Ginani this can be an assumption that may work but it all up to you

Comment: Your *"I think"* IMHO isn't a concrete answer, more of an uncertainty which I'm sure others share my view; this qualifies as being of low-quality. I also noticed that both [Jay Blanchard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard) and I received downvotes at around the same time, since we were both present in your (now deleted and incorrect) answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43680252/1415724 - We voiced our views and there isn't anything wrong with that. If that is the attitude that you wish to have, I can give you a good tip: **lose it.** It will do you more *harm* than **good.**